# Why are there so many partitions in /dev/block/mmcblk0

Tags: sd-card, internal-sd

This is my partition layout printed by fdisk . Why so many partitions and what are they for?

```
Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/block/mmcblk0: 2329 MB, 2329935872 bytes
1 heads, 16 sectors/track, 284416 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16 * 512 = 8192 bytes

              Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks  Id System
/dev/block/mmcblk0p1   *           1          63         500  4d Unknown
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary
/dev/block/mmcblk0p2              63          71          64  45 Unknown
Partition 2 does not end on cylinder boundary
/dev/block/mmcblk0p3              71         634        4500  46 Unknown
Partition 3 does not end on cylinder boundary
/dev/block/mmcblk0p4             634      284672     2272311   5 Extended
Partition 4 does not end on cylinder boundary
/dev/block/mmcblk0p5             634        4384       30000  49 Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p6            4384        5946       12500  50 Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p7            5946        6202        2048  51 Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p8            6202        6586        3072  52 Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p9            6586        6842        2048  53 Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p10           6842        6970        1024  54 Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p11           6971        7098        1024  56 Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p12           7099        8192        8751+ 55 Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p13           8193        8577        3072  4a Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p14           8577        8961        3072  4b Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p15           8961        9089        1024  74 Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p16           9089       10208        8957+ 75 Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p17          10209       10240         256  76 Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p18          10241       10369        1024  47 Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p19          10369       10497        1024  34 Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p20          10497       10657        1280  36 Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p21          10657       11744        8701  71 Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p22          11744       12256        4096  48 Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p23          12257       12288         256  73 Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p24          12289       12544        2047  26 Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p25          12545       83968      571391+ 83 Linux
/dev/block/mmcblk0p26          83969      234368     1203199+ 83 Linux
/dev/block/mmcblk0p27         234369      272768      307199+ 83 Linux
/dev/block/mmcblk0p28         272769      275424       21247+ 19 Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p29         275425      275456         256  23 Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p30            634        4384       30000  49 Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p31           4384        5946       12500  50 Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p32           5946        6202        2048  51 Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p33           6202        6586        3072  52 Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p34           6586        6842        2048  53 Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p35           6842        6970        1024  54 Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p36           6971        7098        1024  56 Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p37           7099        8192        8751+ 55 Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p38           8193        8577        3072  4a Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p39           8577        8961        3072  4b Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p40           8961        9089        1024  74 Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p41           9089       10208        8957+ 75 Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p42          10209       10240         256  76 Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p43          10241       10369        1024  47 Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p44          10369       10497        1024  34 Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p45          10497       10657        1280  36 Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p46          10657       11744        8701  71 Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p47          11744       12256        4096  48 Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p48          12257       12288         256  73 Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p49          12289       12544        2047  26 Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p50          12545       83968      571391+ 83 Linux
/dev/block/mmcblk0p51          83969      234368     1203199+ 83 Linux
/dev/block/mmcblk0p52         234369      272768      307199+ 83 Linux
/dev/block/mmcblk0p53         272769      275424       21247+ 19 Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p54         275425      275456         256  23 Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p55            634        4384       30000  49 Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p56           4384        5946       12500  50 Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p57           5946        6202        2048  51 Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p58           6202        6586        3072  52 Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p59           6586        6842        2048  53 Unknown
/dev/block/mmcblk0p60     

  6842        6970        1024  54 Unknown
```

Comment: I don't think this is a question for end-users (maybe for power-users), but even if: what which partition is for is pretty device dependent IMHO. You could use the `mount` command to isolate some of them (those which are currently mounted). What is the purpose (issue you need to solve) behind the question? With that, we might be able to offer additional help.

Answer (score 4):

Usually you can get some human readable partition names using:

```
 find /dev/block -path \*/by-name -exec ls -l {} \;
```